# System won't respond to Power Switch

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I ran into a problem - I can't start my new system at all: when Power Switch is pressed *nothing* is hapenning, even cpu/system fans are not moving for a split second.

And I just was at the shop where I had bought everything - they started it without any problems, might I say they used their own PSU - I'm reusing mine from the previous build and it's functioning well - I just got back to my old mobo+cpu and everything is ok.

**Specs:**

- Motherboard: Gigabyte Z97P-D3 (in manual it says it requires at least 500W, my PSU has 550 and is certified as gold 80+)
- CPU: Intel i5-4690K
- PSU: Seasonic SSP-550RT
- RAM: 2x8Gb Kingston 1600Mhz Red Fury
- Video: ZOTAC GeForce GTX 660 2Gb DDR5 AMP! Edition

I guess other specs are irrelevant (two fans, 1 ssd and hdd, video). I even tried disconnecting video card power - didn't help.

I also tried reseating ATX and ATX 12V (there are 2x12V connectors/cables on mobo and PSU), flipped around the power switch pin connector - even tried touching pins with a metal screwdriver - the system doesn't respond at all. I'm baffled, does anyone have a suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: You say you disconnected your video card power yet you don't list a GPU in your specifications.

Comment: Sure, added a video spec.

Comment: Go back to the shop and leave with a working pc?

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, but that would be the final stage. Too easy :)

Comment: Given that the GTX 660 itself requires at least a 500W power supply I don't see how you are supplying enough power to your system.

Comment: @Ramhound lol. 1) it's not that video card is using much, if any, power when computer start off; 2) I've been playing few demanding games on max settings on this PSU and video - max power consumption was around 300W.

Comment: You asked if it could be a PSU problem.  I confirmed its a PSU problem based on the fact that particular card requires a 600W PSU.  It was working with a different PSU at the shop, likely one that was greater than 550W, call the shop and ask what PSU they used.

Comment: @Ramhound already 600W? To make it clear - my PSU is fine at handling the load (which, again, is not actually there - it can't even start the system). Also I didn't bring my video while at the shop. As I said initially - I tried disconnecting video too. I might do this all over again, 'cause so far I'm out of options.

Comment: Sounds like you should seek support from somebody familiar with your machine.

Comment: If nothing happened at all, it's probably motherboard's problem

Comment: When I was learning electronics everything was still tubes.  So I studied TV-repair manuals.  In each and every one, step 1 was always "Make sure it is plugged in"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was said numerous times - the issue had nothing to do with PSU not having enough power capacity to power on the system.

This was kinda strange - apparently when I connected some unknown connecter (I have 4 fans in chassis, so there are loads of cabling), which I assumed was one of the fans, to sys_fan_2 pins, the system couldn't be started (even with me shortening the power pins with a screwdriver). So I just left out this sys_fan_2 and everything is OK. I'd guess that connector being connected created some sort of power loop and prevented system from booting, who knows.

Comment: We have an Asrock Motherboard that when a powered USB hub is connected sometimes the computer will not boot.  We disconnect the power from the hub and all boots perfectly.  Points is there are lots of incompatibilities and "bugs" that exist.  The hard part is tracking them down sometimes!